# How to Push Up main layout while keyboard is open

Tags: android, android-layout, view, keyboard, android-xml

> I am working on application when user can search other users,

here is my first screen [image]

> now , when user starts to search other user, the keyboards hides the
>   result

[image]

> I want to move the layout up when user open the keyboard so that user can see few results at least 3.

I also tried this, but nothing happening.

```
  getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

> here is my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/header_layout"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/finder_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="132dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/autotextview_pfinder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:background="@mipmap/search_finderbg"
                android:drawableRight="@mipmap/search_selected"
                android:hint="@string/people_entertainment"
                android:autoText="true"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="23dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:background="@mipmap/search_bottom_finderbg">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@mipmap/user" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_users"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@mipmap/users" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_users"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/group"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_production"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_production"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@mipmap/tv" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_production"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/production"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_all"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_all"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@mipmap/search_selected" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_all"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/all"
                    android:textColor="@color/colororangetext"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_upname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@mipmap/upside_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_upgroup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@mipmap/upside_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_upproduction"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@mipmap/upside_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_upall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:background="@mipmap/upside_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:numColumns="2" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please show your `xml` code.

Comment: @jaydroider, please check